# How to install the printer drivers silently by python script into client end without user interactions

Tags: python

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

import getpass

url = "https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softlib/software13/COL64388/al-154900-1/Full_Webpack-36.2.117-DJ5810_Full_Webpack.exe"

print('File Downloading')

usrname = getpass.getuser()
destination = f'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Install Exe\\printer_driver.exe'

download = urlretrieve(url, destination)

print('File downloaded')

import subprocess

result = subprocess.call('"C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Install Exe\\printer_driver.exe" /S norestart ', shell=True)
print(result)
```

Comment: That sounds like something that someone with bad intentions would try to do.

Comment: No it is a requirement for my project to install printer drivers

Comment: @RishiVashishtha *Perhaps* what you say is true, but we don't *know* it to be true...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.